# "File does not exist" in apache error log

Tags: htaccess, apache, mod-rewrite, 404

This is an example of an error in out log file:

> `File does not exist: /var/www/website/female, referer: http://www.example.com/female/dresses/A-Dress-Black`

`/female` does not physically exist, because we use friendly URLs via our `.htaccess` file which looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{http_host} !^www.website.com$ [nc]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.website.com/$1 [r=301,nc,L]
RewriteRule ^News/?$ news.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^About/?$ about.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Contact/?$ contact.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Sign-In/Create-Account?$ sign_up_in.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Logout?$ sign_up_in.php?l=1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Your-Bag?$ your_bag.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Help?$ help.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Profile?$ profile.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^Create-Profile?$ profile_create.php [NC,L]
# ITEM
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ store_focus.php?sex=$1catName=$2&permalink=$3 [NC,L]
# PAGE
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z-]+)/page/([0-9]+)/?$ store.php?sex=$1&catName=$2&page=$3 [NC,L]
# CATEGORY
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z-]+)/?$ store.php?sex=$1&catName=$2 [NC,L]
# SEX
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]+)/?$ store.php?sex=$1 [NC,L]
```

Every request for a page results in an error even though the site works fine. Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: I still  haven't got to the bottom of this... really annoying!

Comment: Asked April 2010 .. Last answer Feb 2011, OP's last comment dated March 2011 .. and still no solution? Doh. 1) There is missing `&` in ITEM rule: `store_focus.php?sex=$1catName=` should be `store_focus.php?sex=$1&catName=` 2) Individual pages rewrite rules have missing `/` before `?`: `^Profile?$` should be `^Profile/?$`

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to match a path that starts with a letter or number, but it starts with a '/'. Your rules should be something like

```
RewriteRule ^/([A-Za-z0-9-])/...$      ...
```

Alos, do you have access to the logs? If so, enable the logs for mog_rewrite

```
RewriteLog /some/path
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

Comment: Unfortunately It gives me an error when I add a "/". Do you really need the "/" if you have RewriteBase = "/"
---- The requested URL /female/just-arrived/page/1 was not found on this server.

Comment: I do not think RewriteBase does what you think... Try remove it.

Comment: No difference, damn!

Comment: Edited my answer with more ideas

Comment: Ah good idea.. didn't realise you could log rewrites.
I've got the log here: http://79.125.18.68/rwlog.txt
Just trying to make some sense of it.

Comment: From the log, it seems to be working. Do you still have problems?

Comment: We don't have any problems per se, just entries in the log saying it thinks there are problems!

Comment: "...but it starts with a `/`" - The URL-path that the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ matches against does not start with a slash when used in `.htaccess` (_directory_ context). That would only apply if the directives are being used directly in a _server_ or _virtualhost_ context (which does not apply here).

Answer (score 2):

If your Rewrite rules are in an .htaccess file, you need to have at least

```
AllowOverride FileInfo
```

in your apache configuration.

And you also need to have

```
Options FollowSymLinks
```

If your server configuration has

```
AllowOverride FileInfo Options
```

(or AllowOverride All) then you can also add Options FollowSymlinks to the .htaccess file.

Comment: I don't use .htacces..All options are set in the VHost.

Comment: The OP has stated that "the site works fine", so the `.htaccess` rules must already be working satisfactorily. If the problem was to do with `AllowOverride` or `Options` then the site wouldn't work at all.

Answer (score 1):

There is a decent chance that the error doe not come from the page itself but rather from an element on the page.

Example: `<img src="img/bla.jpg"/>` would point to `/female/dresses/img/bla.jpg` instead of `/img/bla.jpg`.

Because the server first checks for the female folder when it's searching for the bla.jpg, it will never give the error on the element itself

Comment: Thank you! I had the same problem and in my case it was because the web browser was searching for the favincon.png file with a relative path.

Comment: "There is a decent chance that the error doe not come from the page itself" - although the URL quoted in the error log would seem to be the "page itself"?

Answer (score 0):

Been a while since I used Apache or wrote any Rewrite Rules, but are trying to match any number of A-Za-z and - do you not need to escape the last - "-"

or is the last - doing something special I would guess that's your problem if your trying to match -'s

```
# ITEM
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ store_focus.php?sex=$1catName=$2&permalink=$3 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hmm, that's not it. The hyphen can be anywhere outside of a range, unescaped.

Comment: Sometimes the log just looks like this: [Wed Apr 14 15:18:37 2010] [error] [client 81.138.14.83] File does not exist: /var/www/website/female

Comment: another thing I notice is that you are looking for something that begins with a letter or - 

<pre>^([A-Za-z-]+)</pre>

after a quick glance as the rewrite docs at httpd.apache.org they look like that all start by looking for a / the one after the domain name. You are not trying to find this first /

Comment: so you think it should be
RewriteRule ^/([A-Z......... ?

Comment: "The hyphen can be anywhere outside of a range, unescaped." - yes, at the start or end of the character class.

Comment: "so you think it should be `RewriteRule ^/([A-Z.........` ?" - No, the `RewriteRule` _pattern_ should only be prefixed with `/` (ie. root-relative) if the directive is used in a _server_ or _virtualhost_ context, not `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. A work-around is to create the directory that is reported to be missing.

```
mkdir /var/www/website/female
```

Once it gets past the directory check, the RewriteRule will probably work. It's a mystery to me why it first checks the existence of the directory.