# “File does not exist” in Apache error log when mod_rewrite is using

Tags: apache, htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache-log-files

I am getting below error in server log, when re-writing the URLs.

```
[Fri Jan 25 11:32:57 2013] [error] [client ***IP***] File does not exist: /home/testserver/public_html/testing/flats-in-delhi-for-sale, referer: http://domain.in/testing/flats-in-delhi-for-sale/
```

I searched very where, but not found any solution.

My *.htaccess* config is given below:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
Options All -Indexes

ErrorDocument 404 http://domain.in/testing/404.php

RewriteEngine On

#Category Link
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)-in-([a-zA-Z]+)-([a-zA-Z-]+)/?$ view-category.php?type=$1&dis=$2&cat=$3 [NC,L]

#Single Property Link
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z]+)-in-([a-zA-Z]+)-([a-zA-Z-]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)/?$ view-property.php?type=$1&district=$2&category=$3&title_alias=$4 [NC,L]
```

I also found similar old dated question, but no answer (["File does not exist" in apache error log](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/16606/file-does-not-exist-in-apache-error-log)).

Thanks in advance for your help.

P.S.: My site is working fine even Apache log is showing the error.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar situation yesterday. My website was working fin, but there were errors in Apache's error log. The problem was caused by a mistake in my PHP files, not in my `RewriteRule`.

My PHP files contained the following fragment:

```
<script src="javascript/package-min-1367246122.js"></script>
```

The missing slash caused "file does not exist" errors in Apache's error log. This the correct fragment:

```
<script src="/javascript/package-min-1367246122.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You may have used a `,` in some `<img>` tag. For example:

```
<img src="/testing/flats-in-delhi-for-sale,">
<script src="/testing/flats-in-delhi-for-sale,"></script>
```

Don't forget that the URL is very sensitive to any character.

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to check the paths in your configuration *.htacess* file. If the error (file doesn't exist is shown), then the script can't find the file mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My site is working fine even Apache log is showing the error.